# Samsung phones can't connect with similar mac address devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mac-address

I have problem to establish bluetooth connection on Samsung phone.

Devices are based on Nordic Semiconductor's nRF52 chip.

```
> Device 1: 0C:8C:DC:1F:CB:9D
> 
> Device 2: 0C:8C:DC:1F:CB:63
```

Samsung phone can connect with 1 device but connection with 2 is not possible.

In logs looks like Samsung phone is trying to connect with address:

```
0C:8C:DC:1F:CB:XX
```

Samsung just only masking mac address or what is it?

Tested on:

> Samsung J3 Samsung J5 Samsung S5 Samsung S7